# Jenkins run build in docker on server (withDockerServer not working)

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to run my build inside a docker; but I don't want the docker to run on the jenkins master but on another server that has docker running.

What does work:

- inside jenkins configure a docker Cloud to connect to docker server (using tcp://my-server:4243)
- configure a docker agent template for certain docker images and assign labels to those docker containers (these need to be containers with sshd running; java installed etc such that they can be connected as jenkins slaves)
- in my build I specify that I want the build to run on that label

What does not work:

```
pipeline {
        agent any
        stages {
                stage('test') {
                        steps { script {
                                withDockerServer([uri: 'tcp://my-server:4243']) {
                                        withDockerContainer([image: 'alpine']) {
                                                sh "whoami; pwd; ls /usr/local/bin"
                                        }
                                }
                        } }
                }
        }
}
```

in this case I get errors:

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

since docker is not installed on my jenkins master; this means he is trying to execute the docker image on my jenkins master and not on my-server... any tips?

I am using:

- jenkins 2.150.3
- docker plugin 1.1.6
- docker pipeline 1.17

**EDIT**
even with scripted pipeline this does not work:

```
node('master') {
        withDockerServer([uri: 'tcp://my-server:4243']) {
                withDockerContainer([image: 'alpine']) {
                        sh "whoami; pwd; ls /usr/local/bin"
                }
        }       
}
```

he is still ignoring `withDockerServer` (it is shown in the pipeline.log, but the docker command is still run on jenkins master)

Answer (score 1):

apparently `docker` needs to be installed on jenkins master in order for jenkins to be able to launch the docker on the server.

After installation of `docker` (even without the `docker` daemon running on jenkins master); jenkins was able to launch the docker on **my-server**.